# Does the negative sign in the Lagrangian $L=T-V$ relate to the $(+,-,-,-)$ Minkowski signature of relativity?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, metric-tensor, potential-energy, relativity

I've read many derivations of the Euler-Lagrange equation, but this is more of a physics-philosophical point.

Kinetic energy $T$ involves *time* derivatives, while potential involves *spatial* location. In relativity, time and space show up with opposite signs, (+,-,-,-). In the wave equation they do too ($f_{tt}-f_{xx}... = 0$). In purely spatial problems, such as "how does a trampoline settle under a point force"), we use Poisson's equation, which is purely spatial and only involves positive quantities.

Is there an umbrella method whereby both spatial and spatio-temporal problems all appear as minimizations? I sense a connection, but I don't quite see it.

Comment: Short answer: No. After all, the Lagrangian method can also be used to describe Galilean mechanics in exactly the same way.

Comment: @balu The only difference in the Galilean mechanics is the infinite speed of light, but the metric signature is effectively the same. Strictly speaking, the space and time metrics are separate in the Galilean mechanics. However, since nothing real is infinite, you can think of the speed of light being simply very very large. Then the Galilean spacetime is just the Minkowski spacetime with non-relativistic velocities, but the same metric signature. In other words, the difference between space and time is not removed in the Galilean mechanics.

Comment: To calculate geodesics in a spacetime given by a metric you simply use the metric as a Lagrangian and solve the EL equations. Thus your intuition seems to have some support.

Comment: @safephere I strongly disagree with your statement that "the metric signature is effectively the same". As you say, "the space and time metrics are separate in the Galilean mechanics" and for this reason we *cannot* treat the Galilean world as Minkowski space with an incredibly high, but finite speed of light $c$. The limit $c \rightarrow \infty$ you're describing does *not* work. To see this, consider that the speed of light in natural units will always be $1$. Put differently (in more mathematical terms), Sylvester's law of inertia will always give the usual Minkowski metric. In particular…

Comment: …the isometry group (= the Poincaré group $ISO(1, 3)$ and thus the causal structure will always be the same, for all $c < \infty$. Yes, from a purely mathematical point of view there is a way to make sense of the limit $ISO(1, 3) \rightarrow G$, where $G$ is the Galilean group (see "Group contraction" on Wikipedia) but I'd argue that this has no physical relevance.

Answer (score 2):

Mostly *No,* but sometimes *Yes.* E.g. in the Lagrangian density

$$ {\cal L}~=~\frac{1}{2}\partial_{\mu}\phi ~\eta^{\mu\nu}\partial_{\nu}\phi -{\cal V}(\phi) ~=~\frac{1}{2}\dot{\phi}^2 \underbrace{\color{red}{-} \frac{1}{2}(\nabla\phi)^2 \color{red}{-} {\cal V}(\phi)}_{\color{red}{\text{minus}} \text{ potential terms}} $$

the first (second) $\color{red}{\text{minus}}$ in the potential terms is related (not related) to the Minkowski signature $(+,\color{red}{-},\color{red}{-},\color{red}{-})$, respectively.